# How to create "virtual root" with Python's ElementTree?

Tags: python, elementtree

I am trying to use Python's ElementTree to generate an XHTML file.

However, the ElementTree.Element() just lets me create a single tag (e.g., HTML).
I need to create some sort of a virtual root or whatever it is called so that I can put the various , DOCTYPES, etc.

How do I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better way but I've seen this done:

Create the base document as a string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html></html>
```

Then parse that string to start your new document.

Comment: +1, confirmed, elementtree cannot add/create doctype (but can parse it!), so this solution is as clean as it gets.

Comment: It appear that this does not work any more: `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET; string = '''<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\n<html></html>''';print(ET.tostring(ET.fromstring(string), encoding='unicode'))` emits only `<html />`

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. When parsing a document and writing the docuemnt back again the doc-type definition is not present anymore. I  found a solution browsing the documentation:

[link text](http://effbot.org/zone/element-tidylib.htm)

Saving HTML Files #

To save a plain HTML file, just write out the tree.

```
tree.write("outfile.htm")
```

This works well, as long as the file doesn’t contain any embedded SCRIPT or STYLE tags.

If you want, you can add a DTD reference to the beginning of the file:

```
file = open("outfile.htm", "wb")
file.write(DTD + "\n")
tree.write(file)
file.close()
```

Comment: Using Python 3.6, this does not work out-of-the-box but can be easily fixed. One must open the file with `"wb"` instead of `"w"` and use `.encode()` on the prefix string as `file.write` expects a binary parameter with `"wb"`.