# How to create <!DOCTYPE> with Python's cElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have tried to use the answer in this question, but can't make it work: [How to create "virtual root" with Python's ElementTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070772/how-to-create-virtual-root-with-pythons-elementtree)

Here's my code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree
from StringIO import StringIO
s = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM \"tmx14a.dtd\" ><tmx version=\"1.4a\" />'
tree = ElementTree.parse(StringIO(s)).getroot()
header = ElementTree.SubElement(tree,'header',{'adminlang': 'EN',})
body = ElementTree.SubElement(tree,'body')
ElementTree.ElementTree(tree).write('myfile.tmx','UTF-8')
```

When I open the resulting 'myfile.tmx' file, it contains this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tmx version="1.4a"><header adminlang="EN" /><body /></tmx>
```

What am I missing? or, is there a better tool?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [lxml](http://lxml.de) and its `tostring` function:

```python
from lxml import etree

s = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4a"/>""" 

tree = etree.fromstring(s)
header = etree.SubElement(tree,'header',{'adminlang': 'EN'})
body = etree.SubElement(tree,'body')

print etree.tostring(tree, encoding="UTF-8",
                     xml_declaration=True,
                     pretty_print=True,
                     doctype='<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14a.dtd">')
```

=>

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14a.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4a">
  <header adminlang="EN"/>
  <body/>
</tmx>
```

Comment: I get this error: `ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.` with Python 3.6

Comment: `etree.fromstring(s.encode("UTF-8"))` works for me with Python 3.6.

Answer (score 17):

You could set [xml_declaration](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) argument on `write` function to `False`, so output won't have xml declaration with encoding, then just append what header you need manually. Actually if you set your encoding as 'utf-8' (lowercase), xml declaration won't be added too.

```python
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.Element('tmx', {'version': '1.4a'})
ElementTree.SubElement(tree, 'header', {'adminlang': 'EN'})
ElementTree.SubElement(tree, 'body')

with open('myfile.tmx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14a.dtd">'.encode('utf8'))
    ElementTree.ElementTree(tree).write(f, 'utf-8')
```

Resulting file (newlines added manually for readability):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14a.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4a">
    <header adminlang="EN" />
    <body />
</tmx>
```

Comment: can you explain how did you added new line to the xml?

Comment: @Learner: I added it manually for readability. If you want to have XML with new lines from ElementTree - search how to pretty print XML.

Comment: This gives me an error `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes` in python 3.6.4 on macOS.  I think it's because you are writing first as a string, then as binary in the same open() command.

Comment: @ElliottB thanks, I updated code. Should work on both python 2 and 3.

Comment: This solution doesn't work, except if you enter manually (as said) the ElementTree which is surely not what you want to do. I put a simple & stupid solution to this problem below.

Comment: @Learner You could simply insert a "\n" (without quotes) into the string between the XML declaration and the doctype.

Answer (score 2):

I used different solution to add DOCTYPE, very simple, very stupid.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open(path_file, "w", encoding='UTF-8') as xf:
    doc_type = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE dlg:window ' \
               'PUBLIC "-//OpenOffice.org//DTD OfficeDocument 1.0//EN" "dialog.dtd">'
    tostring = ET.tostring(root).decode('utf-8')
    file = f"{doc_type}{tostring}"
    xf.write(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution to this problem either using vanilla ElementTree, and the solution proposed by demalexx created non-valid XML that was rejected by my application (DITA).
What I propose is a workaround involving other modules and it works perfectly for me.

```
import re
# found no way for cleanly specify a <!DOCTYPE ...> stanza in ElementTree so
# so we substitute the current <?xml ... ?> stanza with a full <?xml... + <!DOCTYPE...
new_header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n' \
                 '<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">\n'

target_xml = re.sub(u"\<\?xml .+?>", new_header, source_xml)
with open(filename, 'w') as catalog_file:
    catalog_file.write(target_xml.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "non-valid XML" problem?

Comment: @posfan12, I'll guess that the main issue would have been not having the DTD at the beginning of the line, which is easy to fix in demalexx's answer.