# Header for XML files with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

with the module `xml.etree.ElementTree` I can pretty much create an XML file as I like, except for the most important part ( in my case ): the header.

I can't find a real solution for that, my header is a costant string that I'm supposed to put right between `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and the first xml element; any clean solutions to this ?

---

What I mean with header it's the same thing that sometime it's called DTD ( document type definition )

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd">

<svg>
  ....
</svg>
```

I need to write the

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd">
```

part inside the file.

Comment: Can you give an example of what kind of text you need to insert? Valid XML doesn't give you much room as to what is *legal* between the prolog and the root XML element.

Comment: @MartijnPieters more details added

Comment: See [How to create <!DOCTYPE> with Python's cElementTree](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8868248)